# Selecting a specific color in GIMP (without clicking)

Tags: gimp

I'm looking for a stray pixel in a bmp using GIMP. Ideally, I could simply select a specific color; however, the only method I've so far been able to find is to use the "select by color" tool. This requires clicking on the color I want to select within the picture. However, I need to select one where I don't specifically know that it even exists.

(The bmp also has a palette with one or two very similar color, so I need to be sure that I have the right color.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to the use of a Graphics Program and should be on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

- add a small layer above your image, fill it with required color
- restore your image layer as the active layer
- start the Color-select tool, make sure the `Sample merged` option is checked
- click in the color layer